# Multiple clients for multiple purposes in TCP socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

After seeing some examples at my class, I know that if I want to send a "TypeA" object to server and receive a "ProcessedA" object as a result, I only need one client class.

But if I want to send "TypeA", "TypeB", and "TypeC" objects (not at the same time) to server, do I need to make 3 different client classes, each one of which sends objects of one of those data types, or I only need to make one client class and write 3 different "send" methods?

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one method if the objects you send inherits from one unique class or interface, and the same logic is applied to the result class.
It's a bit hard to understand what you need if you don't include a sample code of what you are trying (as is noticed in another post related to your request).
If this condition can be met by your needs, you can use the instanceof operator inside the server method to detect the type of the received object and cast it to the known child type. And apply the same logic to proccess the response in the client.